# How to set Items to "completed" using EWS

Tags: exchangewebservices

I want to get attachments from emails stored in a public folder on our Exchange 2010 Server, and after saving the attachments to files, I want to mark the emails as "completed".

It is easy to get the list of emails, and the property `TaskSchema.IsComplete` works as intended for filtering the search result: ("posteingang" is the public folder I want to search)

```
    FindItemsResults<Item> findItemResults;
    ItemView               view = new ItemView(50);

    findItemResults = service.findItems(posteingang.getId(),
                                        new SearchFilter.SearchFilterCollection(
                                            LogicalOperator.And,
                                            new SearchFilter.ContainsSubstring(ItemSchema.Subject, "example"),                                                
                                            new SearchFilter.IsNotEqualTo(TaskSchema.IsComplete, true)
                                        ),
                                        view);

        service.loadPropertiesForItems(findItemResults, PropertySet.FirstClassProperties);
        for (Item item : findItemResults) {

                EmailMessage msg = (EmailMessage) item;
                msg.setIsRead(true);
                msg.setCategories(SL_DARVIN);
                msg.setImportance(Importance.Low);
                msg.update(ConflictResolutionMode.AlwaysOverwrite);

        }
```

However, when it comes to the part where I want to mark the email as complete, I have no clue how to do so. Casting an `item` to a `task` won't work :-(

Does anybody have an idea?

P.S.: The code examples are in Java, but thanks to the EWS API they should be almost identical in C#.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to mark it as complete using the extended properties eg something like

```
        ExtendedPropertyDefinition PidTagFlagStatus = new ExtendedPropertyDefinition(0x1090, MapiPropertyType.Integer);
        ExtendedPropertyDefinition PidTagFlagCompleteTime = new ExtendedPropertyDefinition(0x1091, MapiPropertyType.SystemTime);
        ExtendedPropertyDefinition PidLidTaskComplete = new ExtendedPropertyDefinition(DefaultExtendedPropertySet.Task, 0x811C,MapiPropertyType.Boolean);            
        ExtendedPropertyDefinition PidLidCommonEnd = new ExtendedPropertyDefinition(DefaultExtendedPropertySet.Common, 0x8517, MapiPropertyType.SystemTime);
        ExtendedPropertyDefinition PidLidTaskStatus = new ExtendedPropertyDefinition(DefaultExtendedPropertySet.Task, 0x8101, MapiPropertyType.Integer);
        ExtendedPropertyDefinition PidLidPercentComplete = new ExtendedPropertyDefinition(DefaultExtendedPropertySet.Task, 0x8102, MapiPropertyType.Double);
        ExtendedPropertyDefinition TaskDateCompleted = new ExtendedPropertyDefinition(DefaultExtendedPropertySet.Task, 0x810F, MapiPropertyType.SystemTime);
        ExtendedPropertyDefinition PidTagFollowupIcon = new ExtendedPropertyDefinition(0x1095, MapiPropertyType.Integer);


        Message.SetExtendedProperty(PidTagFlagStatus, 0x00000001);
        Message.SetExtendedProperty(PidTagFlagCompleteTime, DateTime.Now);
        Message.SetExtendedProperty(PidLidTaskComplete, true);
        Message.SetExtendedProperty(PidLidCommonEnd, DateTime.Now);
        Message.SetExtendedProperty(PidLidTaskStatus, 2);
        Message.SetExtendedProperty(PidLidPercentComplete, 1);
        Message.SetExtendedProperty(TaskDateCompleted, DateTime.Now);
        Message.SetExtendedProperty(PidTagFollowupIcon, 3);
        Message.Update(ConflictResolutionMode.AlwaysOverwrite);
```